# Is EQ the only reason pickups sound different?

Tags: electric-guitar, electric-bass-guitar

Do electric guitar (or bass) pickups sound different only because of EQ?

I understand the strength of magnet and totality of wire windings effects the strength of the signal but if one wanted to make one pickup sound like another would a very good EQ be able to achieve that?

That is, why buy multiple electric guitars if you can get an EQ that can 'tune in' the sound of any pickup.

(For this discussion please ignore 'tone wood'. I have seen many videos attempting to demonstrate the effect of wood on solid body guitar tone and the differences seem minor at best, but significant on an acoustic.)

Comment: It's a fair question, I don't understand the downvote. In essence you're asking, could a magnetic pickup be simulated with a sufficiently detailed EQ curve. This idea of simulating equivalence is like with speaker cabinets, which - excluding unwanted distortion - can be reproduced with impulse responses that are so short that they can be said to be equivalent to very detailed EQ curves. But pickups - is there more to them. It's not self-evidently clear that there's more, so it's a fair question.

Comment: As a side note, I noticed that if you put EMG pickups on differentguitars, you get  an EMG sound, with more or less sustain depending on the guitar. Many characteristics seem to disappear behind the sound of these pickups.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica  Why a downvote? Easy answer. If the answer isn't absolutely perfect for the person reading the answer it's a downvote. In 50 questions I've posted, and I'm not a bad writer, I've had perhaps 3 with net-positive ratings.

Comment: @Thomas You're probably thinking of EMG's *active* pickups (ie: the 81/85, etc), and that's more a trait of active pickups generally - nothing particular about EMG.  Other active pickups behave similarly, while EMG also makes passive pickups with a more traditional response.

Comment: @J..., yes, you're right, I have only experience with the common 81/85 combo. I found that it doesn't matter the guitar, the pickups have their own tone which is great for metal.

Comment: If you're a 1000 times better at sound engineering than you are at playing, sure. Depends on how bad the *garbage in* is and how hard you want to work at it, instead of just using the thing that doesn't require post production in the first place. With just an EQ though, IDK - if you're a wizard. A full sound stage, a DAW, *and a sound engineer*, no problem. How many zeros you got?

Comment: The pickups may be non-linear (roughly speaking - adds harmonics). That won't be simulatable with EQ (and to the extent it is fixable, you'd need different settings for each note). For instance (extreme example), if the physical sound the pickup receives is a sine wave, and pickup A clips it so the electrical signal looks more like a square wave, you are going to have a hard time simulating that with EQ on pickup B which does not clip.

Comment: @abligh That's true! The question presumes they are solely affecting EQ.

Comment: In addition to changing the timbre, there are significant and complex physical interactions happening between all the components, including strings and pickups. Physical _energy_ is being transmitted from the vibration of the strings. If the guitar is connected to an input of too low impedance, it shortens the sound and the strings lose energy faster. Etc. The interactions are very complex, far from a linear "EQ" sort of system. For example if you compare humbuckers to single-coils, the sound and dynamic contour is different and not only the spectral shape.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica  It's true but for a solid body guitar I've yet to see a video showing any significant difference as there is with acoustics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EQ is a *linear* change of signal: it does not matter in which order you place the EQ sections for the result of sound, and if you double the signal in front, you get out exactly double the previous result at the end.

A pickup, in contrast, has the magnetic flux through its coils modified as the string travels through its magnetic circuit and completes it in some manner.  If it were working in a linear manner, there would be no difference between playing louder and cranking the volume pot up.

That may work to some approximation when you *microphone* your electric guitar and amplify those results (or rather record them if you are not keen on feedback).  There are things like piezo bridge pickups: those will tend to have a better chance of being made to sound similar via EQ since they have a comparatively linear, "microphoning" response.  That does not mean that the frequency response is even, but merely that it is in some fixed relation to the input frequencies, and with EQ you can tweak that relation.

But the magnetic pickup action is rather far from being a linear thing so you'd need something seriously more contorted to have a chance to map one kind of pickup to the sound of another.

Comment: "it does not matter in which order you place the EQ sections for the result of sound" ... Please clarify "EQ sections" ... I picture an EQ daily chained with a distortion unit and I think the before/after might matter ... it seems the EQ would always be first because it's about getting the frequencies as opposed to 'coloring' the sound.

Comment: @RandyZeitman Linear system means that in theory there could be a corresponding reversing "undo" system which gives the original signal. For EQ it's theoretically like this. If the EQs are linear, it doesn't matter in which order you place them, the end-result is the same. But if you have a non-linear system such as a distortion pedal - or any processing which causes distortion - then there is no perfect "undo" even in theory. Something is lost within the process. And then the processing order matters. For example, dynamics processors such as compressors are non-linear systems.

Comment: I understand what you mean but do you perhaps mean reciprocal instead of linear. If a transformation has an inverse then that's an undo and not all transformations are linear (natural log?)

Comment: @Randy Zeitman - Linear is the correct term, in the sense of a mathematically linear system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_system). The "multiple EQ sections" is referencing if you had multiple EQs run one after another; if you had 2 EQs with different settings and connected input->EQ1->EQ2->output, the output would be the same as if you connected input->EQ2->EQ1->output - the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica "Linear system means that in theory there could be a corresponding reversing "undo" system" - That line might confuse people, since it sounds like it's meant to be a loose definition of "linear".  I can design a distortion circuit with a corresponding "undistortion" circuit.  That doesn't make it linear (but if there was no possible undo, then at least we know it's definitely nonlinear)

Comment: Ok, I read the Wiki article ...linear means superposition which means the various stimuli on a system interact but without reaction. For example, adding lemon to tea ... the lemon distributes but it doesn't change the chemistry of the tea ... you could remove the lemon and be back to tea, vs. lemon + milk which would curdle. The Beatles ... non-linear ... the sum is more than it's parts! LOL!

Comment: Linear transformations are not necessarily commutative nor invertible.  What distinguishes a linear transformation from a non-linear one is that putting two signals through a linear transformation individually and then adding the result will have the same effect as adding the two signals together and putting the sum through that same transformation.

Comment: As Logan and supercat wrote: linearity is not the same as invertibility, however it _is_ as a rule of thumb much more likely / feasible for a linear transformation to be invertible than for a nonlinear one. — It's good that you bring up the linearity property, however also ironic because a pickup **is** in fact to good approximation linear. The reason playing louder sounds different from turning up the volume has other reasons: **a)** the strings vibrate inherently different **b)** the volume pot on an electric guitar actually doesn't control just volume but also timbre.

Comment: BTW the fact that you can arbitrarily change the order of two EQs also doesn't follow from their linearity. In general, for two linear operators _A_ and _B_, you will have _A∘B_ ≠ _B∘A_. If both orders are the same, the operators are said to _commute_. A sufficient condition for operators to commute is if they're both [_time invariant_ (LTI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system) – EQs and pickups are. An example of linear effect that's not LTI is a chorus. (Chorus and EQ almost commute, but two different choruses can sound notably different depending on which is first.)

Comment: Are pickups really linear? What I remember from physics lectures is that ferromagnetic materials have all kinds of weird behaviour and permanent magnets are even weirder.

Comment: @ojs They certainly do NOT seem linear which seems to be the core distinction of answering the question "no" ... attack, sustain, delay ... is separate from EQ.

Answer (score 11):

From a physics perspective...

Different pickups have different magnetic fields. The magnetic fields have different shapes and sizes.

Part of what makes typical humbuckers sound different from single-coil pickups is the fact that the magnetic field on a humbucker covers more of the string. When it covers more of the string, that means that the string's higher modes (higher frequencies) will cancel out more. This is **part** of why typical single-coil pickups sound brighter than P90s, and P90s typically sound brighter than humbuckers.

Another factor that makes pickups sound different is the overall frequency response of the pickup. When you add more windings to a pickup, the output levels get higher, but it also increases the inductance and parasitic capacitance of the pickup, which makes the pickup sound darker. The wire also has resistance to it, and a higher resistance (thinner wire) will dampen the natural resonance of the pickup (reduce the Q factor).

In theory, you can adjust for the frequency response with EQ, but you cannot use EQ to adjust how big the magnetic field is. The problem is that making the magnetic field bigger, like for a humbucker, has a different effect on each string.

The reason why it affects each string differently is because you can think of it kind of like an EQ, except instead of applying an EQ to different *frequencies,* the EQ applies to different *wavelengths.* For example, if you have a magnetic field that is 2cm wide, then it will pick up a wavelength of 8cm just fine, but a wavelength of 2cm will be highly attenuated.

Each string has a different relationship between wavelength and frequency. So, changing the shape of the magnetic field is kind of like applying a different EQ curve to each string! Once all the strings are mixed together, you can't do that. That is why it is not possible to make a humbucker sound like a single coil pickup, or vice versa, using EQ.

Now consider that different pickups have lots of different magnetic fields. For example, you can get pickups with pole magnets or bar magnets. Also consider that when a string vibrates, it moves through different parts of the magnetic field... if you hit a string hard, it won't line up with the pole pieces, but with a bar magnet, that doesn't apply. These are differences that you can't just EQ out.

Comment: This is the single best explanation for what makes pickups different, that I have ever read.

Comment: It's incorrect to say that "Each string has a different relationship between wavelength and frequency". Wavelength is the reciprocal of frequency as a fact of physics. Each note has a specific wavelength.

Comment: @Kylotan If that were true, then all open strings would sound the same note. The relationship between wavelength and frequency depends on the medium that the wave is traveling through. When you change the weight of the string or change the tension, it changes the frequency, but not the wavelength.

Answer (score -2):

Short Answer is *definitely NO*.

Long Answer. EQ were existing long before digital  signal processing. As it was mentioned, EQ comprises of *Linear Change* of the signal. Let's make it more clear. When you view at the signal as Fourier spectrum over some big approx 0.1s window, *Ideal EQ* only changes relative height of these peaks and does not change the harmonic structure. Technically, EQ is nonlinear operator over spectrum, but they were made to not touch the harmonic structure. Old EQs were just filters of the signal coming over series of RC or RL electric filters. Those were not changing your harmonic structure *FOR SURE*. So *definitely NOT* with passive elements.

Then the era of passive EQs came to an end, and then EQ became all active, which means that there is transistors which are having positive-negative feedbacks. First, making good EQualizer even with todays circuit design is a *HUGE* pain. And all EQ curcuitry had drawbacks as *unwanted* nonlinear actions over your signal. So *deeply theoretically* you can *compensate* for some other elements inside your signal trunk. But doing so with transistor technology is *HUGE pain* up to the point that even now simple analog amplifiers with transistors cannot successfully emulate even other vacuum tube amplifiers (hence the usage of VT amps is not discontinued despite them having their drawbacks).

And now, the digital EQ, which is not actually "real" EQ. Lets see, you got ADC-DAC converting of the signal. Which can only be successful up to some bit depth. I guess the best what today's ADC can do is 12-bit conversion for mass production. So you got discrete time and discrete levels, you are not doing even actual Fourier spectrum via integrating, you are doing Fast Fourier Transform, which only "resembles" the frequency spectrum of your signal. Digital EQ = "FFT image editing". It is not successful in on-the-fly activity. But people are using it a lot to noise-clean or level-edit their voices in-record. Because in studio you can afford to write sound in environment of 100dB accuracy and  with at least 32-bit depth of signal. FFT is moving to it's limit, actual Fourier Transform, at maximum accuracy (infinite bit depth + infinite sampling rate).

Even so, if doing "editing Fourier image" can theoretically lead to editing the tembre or harmonic structure of your signal, which can *mimic* the tembre of instrument or some other element in your "signal trunk". There is *very LITTLE* to do about those harmonics which were suppressed by elements before your digital editing starts. You cannot "uncompress" harmonics which were supressed before because of laws of entropy. Ones your information is lost without backup you cannot turn that process back. Same what happens when you upscale a JPEG image without sophisticated tools.

About sophisticated tools AKA neural network editing etc. It exists, but it exists only for very few tasks which it was calibrated for. Long calibration, testing, huge work just to improve some quality of few tasks like improving the quality of sound from *very old vynil record*.

Comment: How is this related to guitar pickups?